# How to find SAS version from SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas

In my previous work place where I had access to base SAS (running SAS interactively on the server directly), I could find out the current SAS version easily (from the SAS log) by issuing the code `proc setinit; run;`

In my new work place there is no base SAS - only Enterprise Guide. I try running the same code but the SAS version does not appear in the SAS log.

I would like to easily find out the SAS version running on the server from Enterprise Guide. Is this possible or not? If so, how?

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/How-to-identify-the-version-of-SAS-embedded-EG/m-p/106720/highlight/true#M29724

Comment: `proc setinit` would do the job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some other options available rather than using the global macro variables (`&sysver` and `&sysvlong4`), if you prefer point-click options.

First, under Help -> About SAS Enterprise Guide, if you select 'Configuration Details' you can see your SAS system version.

Second, if you select the server in the Servers tree (in the window on the bottom left), and right click->Properties, you will see the SAS version/etc. information.

Third, if you continue in that and select "View Initialization Log", it will show you the initialization log (the bit SAS shows when you start a session in the log).  This includes the version number and some other useful information.

Comment: If someone with a server-only version of SAS can verify if my first option works or not, I'll either remove it or update to remove the last sentence - I only have local SAS installations to check with, and in those cases it displays the local SAS version.

Comment: Hey Joe your first option worked beautifully thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The values you're looking for are stored in automatic macro variables in your system. The code below retrieves the macro variables and prints them to the log for your information.

```
%put ** my information;
%put short version: &sysver;
%put version: &sysvlong4;
%put site #: &syssite;
%put cpu: &sysscp &sysscpl;
```

EDIT: Update answer
You can use PROC PRODUCT_STATUS which is great, since it will print the relevant information to the log.

```
proc product_status;run;
```

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Answer (score 4):

Just run the following code and all available information will be printed automatically.

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
%put _all_;
```

that will display all macro variables available in your session.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I was sure I had it formatted right as it was a copy paste from my current SAS session!

Answer (score 2):

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

You can run this set of code and check the results. It will tell you the version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

`%put &_clientversion;` gives you version.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

Or under the help tab in the top left of the enterprise guide.